# Electroweak Force Capabilities

Tags: electromagnetism, weak-interaction, electroweak

I understand that Electroweak force is the unification of Weak force and electromagnetism, but that are the actual effects or capabilities of this fundamental force? or at the very lease, what are the theorized capabilities of electroweak force?

Comment: What's a force capability? What does Wikipedia say about the Standard Model of Electroweak Interactions?

Comment: All I know is that the Electroweak force is combining electromagnetic and weak force, I don't really know what else it has.

Comment: Surely [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction) details a bit more than that.... surely...

Comment: What about [WP: Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) ??

Comment: From what I understand that EW Interaction is an occurrence that happened back when the Big Bang just happened, correct?

Comment: Not only. It makes the sun burn as we speak.

Comment: Interesting, i thought that was just nuclear fusion.

Comment: Yes, to make deuterium, you [produce neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion#Nuclear_fusion_in_stars) which can only run through the weak interactions.

Comment: Okay, very well, thank you for that, I just found Electroweak matter to be a bit complicated on first interpretation